# How do I get rid of brackets?

Tags: python

```
def name(reading):
    return reading
print(name([[10,9,9,10],2]))
```

When I get the program it prints [[10,9,9,10],2] but I need it to print without the extra brackets ending up with [10,9,9,10],2. I tried using things like (*reading, sep = ", ") but that only works when I use print directly. I ultimately want to know how to make reading = [10,9,9,10],2 and not [[10,9,9,10],2]. Thank you.

Comment: yes I just edited it

Comment: Toxrey, if you are printing a list they will be printed with those extra brackets only. They are not part of the data.

Comment: You are confusing the CONTENTS of your data with the REPRESENTATION of your data.  The brackets are not part of the list.  That's just how Python prints them.  You have a list of two items.  The brackets are totally irrelevant.

Comment: @Toxrey if you want then i have another long way to do that. Just say if you want it

Comment: Can I see the long way?

Comment: Toxrey check my answer. It's the long way

Answer (score 0):

You can return it as a string using `join()`

```
def name(reading):
    return ",".join(str(x) for x in reading)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to print it directly I want reading to equal without the extra hard brackets. So is there any way to change the value of reading into [10,9,9,10],2 without printing?

Comment: Brackets are part of the printed version of the data, they're not in the data itself.

Comment: That's just how lists are printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
reading=[[10,9,9,10],2]
def name(reading):
    solution=""
    reading = [[10,9,9,10],2]
    for i in range(len(reading)):
        solution+=str(reading[i])
        if i<len(reading)-1:
            solution+=","
    return solution
print(name(reading))
```

How About this?

+and you should define reading in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
def name(reading03=[[10,9,9,10],2]):
    reading02 = str(reading03)
    reading01 = reading02.replace("[", "")
    reading = reading01.replace("]", "")
    return reading
print(name)
```

Comment: @Toxrey my long answer